# Windows Service Refuses to start

Tags: windows, wcf, service, hosting

I have hosted a WCF duplex service (`netTcpBinding`) in a Windows Service going by the instructions given in the blog : http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/2096-step-by-step-hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding.aspx

All goes fine till the time I try to start the service. When I attempt to start the service it gives me an error given below:

> The Service1 service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   Access is denied.

Could anyone throw any ideas on this ? I am kinda on a deadline and prompt help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is denied. Something tells me the credentials used for the service do not have access to disk or some other resource consumed by your code.
Are you running the service under a system account or a specific service account you created for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the service or add additional logging in order to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it ended up being related to NTFS encryption... the service in question was being started as a user not authorized on that folder under NTFS EFS. Solution is either to remove EFS from that directory or add the user.

exton explained it [here](http://sy.runcode.us/q/system-error-5-access-is-denied-when-starting-a-net-service%20here).